# How to loop through cells in Google Sheets and log information if specific variables exist

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

You will need this link to solve this: - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11PjVSWPfqOBPSej3AlQ-_T8Bws66kevR08Q2NRTmVcE/edit?usp=sharing

So this is a tricky one. I am looking to loop through the name in Sheet1 Column A, and also loop through the type in Column C. Then if Column A in Sheet1 matches the name of column A in Sheet2, **AND** the type is **"pickup"** I want to log the other information that is in Sheet 1 inside of Column C on Sheet 2. Log the things like "State", "Location", "City" next to the identical name in Sheet 2. I hope that makes sense.

I know I probably need to use a loop within a loop to do all this, but this is as far as I can get as I cannot figure out how to write the loop and then log the rows where the 2 names match.

```
function myFunction() {
   function pullDeliveryNotes()
{
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2");
var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
var dataRange2 = sheet2.getDataRange();
var rng = sheet.getRange(2,1, dataRange.getLastRow()-1,dataRange.getLastColumn());
var rng2 = sheet.getRange(2,3, dataRange.getLastRow()-1,dataRange.getLastColumn());
var rng3 = sheet2.getRange(2,1, dataRange2.getLastRow()-1,dataRange2.getLastColumn());
var rngA = rng.getValues().toString()
var rngB = rng2.getValues().toString()
var rngC = rng3.getValues().toString()
for(var i = 0; i < rng.length; i++) {
  for (var x = 0; x < rng2.length; x++) {
    for (var y = 0; y < rng3.length; y++) {

if (rng[i][x][y].includes(rng3[i][x][y]) && rng2[i][x][y] === "pickUp") {
  Logger.log("We got it")
}

    }
  }
}

}
}
```

Comment: Lets summarize this you want to check Column A of sheet 1 with Column A of sheet 2 and if its matches and it's `pickup` , than you want to paste the "State", "Location", "City"  on those rows of sheet 2 which has that name? right? I mean if it's more than 1 than also it should paste the values

Comment: Yes, but I really just need to post all the values with in the other cells into Column C as one big array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your problem statement.

Try this sample script:-

```
function checkValues() {
   
   const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   const ssSource = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1')
   const ssTarget = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2')
   
   const sourceRange = ssSource.getDataRange().getValues().filter(r=> r[2] === 'Pickup'); // Filtering only pickup values
   const targetRange = ssTarget.getDataRange().getValues();
  
   for(var i = 0 ; i < sourceRange.length ; i++)
   {
        for(var j = 1 ; j < targetRange.length ; j++)
        {
          if(sourceRange[i][0] === targetRange[j][0]) // if name matches
          {
            ssTarget.getRange(`C${j+1}`).setValue(`${sourceRange[i][3]},${sourceRange[i][4]},${sourceRange[i][5]}`)  // set values in column C              
          }
        }
     
   } 
}
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I needed. Thank you so much!

Comment: Do you know what you would do if the name existed multiple times. I edited the sheet to show an example of that in rows 14 & 15 and Jim in 16 & 17. If "bob" exists twice it still only logs the notes for the first instance of his name instead of every time he shows up.